# YouTube Analytics - Quota impact of additional metrics and dimensions

Tags: youtube-api, analytics, quota

The Youtube Analytics API Doc outlines how the cost per API query goes up as the number of metrics and dimensions in the query increases, but it's rather vague (e.g. normal, high, very high). Has anyone know what the hard numbers are that are implied by these guidelines?

[YouTube Analytics API Doc on Quota Costs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports)

I've been trying to determine this through my own testing, but if anyone can provide some actual numbers, or has found detailed doc on the subject, it would be a big help.
Thanks,
Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't currently go into greater detail, as we'd like to retain the flexibility to adjust cost moving forward as we see what usage patterns are like.

Are you actually running into quota issues with the YouTube Analytics API, or are you just curious?

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeff, that makes sense. We are in fact having quota limitation issues, and we've asked our contact at Google to extend our quota. If you could recommend any other approaches we should take, the advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm in the process of putting together a "reference application" for doing large YT Analytics report dumps for all the videos in your account. The philosophy is that quota errors aren't a big deal; if you get one, start an exponential backoff and keep trying to again until the call succeeds. The work-in-progress code is at https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/analytics-dump/analyticsdump.rb

Comment: @JeffPosnick IF i have more than 50,000 users requesting a lot of data, (views, likes, etc.) for the day or for the past week, how do we not run into that issue? Is there a way to get Real-time Analytics?

Comment: Hi @JeffPosnick, I am actually running into quota issues with YouTube analytics API. The default quota of 100,000 requests is not enough. Is there any way I can apply to increase that limit? I can properly define my use case for the additional quota requests.