# YouTube Analytics API Quota Extension Application?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

In the past I've been able to access an online application for a quota extension to the YouTube Analytics API.  Has this link been removed?  I can no longer get to the application page.

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=iq-default&authuser=1

Answer (score 1):

You're right. There seems no way on to increase YouTube Analytics API quota (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Unlike any other Google APIs, YouTube Analytics API doesn't have an option to request for more quota in the Quota tab of your project in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

However, as stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811207/youtube-analytics-quota-impact-of-additional-metrics-and-dimensions), if you get an error and thought that it is related to quota limit, start an [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff) and keep trying again until the call succeeds.