# Still no way to increase the YouTube Analytics API Quota?

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I am looking for a way to increase the queries per day quota for the YouTube Analytics API.  I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704429/youtube-analytics-api-quota-extension-application) question asking the same thing nearly two years ago now - can anyone confirm if the answer is still the same (that there is no way anymore)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question appears to have nothing to do with programming but rather a third party service. I'd recommend asking for help at the [YouTube help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube) or [YouTube support](https://support.google.com/youtube/)

Comment: Yes you're right it has nothing to do with programming but Youtube directs us here for support https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support